# Woocommerce search result showing all products of the shop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

Recently, I got a website developed in WooCommerce by a developing company. Due to his unnecessary money demand, I need to take back my website from him and I did't noticed that product search isn't working.

The issue is whenever I start typing in the search bar, by live search I am getting the product name. But when I search the name of the product or anything and hit enter immediately the search result takes me to the shop page where all products are shown. None of the related products show up. I followed some solution like

I just copied it to function.php, the situation is same.

```
function wp_search_filter($query) {
$url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ( (strpos($url,'post_type=product') !== false) && is_search() ) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'product');
}
return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','wp_search_filter');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the solution on this webpage

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

When I have time I will try to create a better explanation,
I would recommend you work with a custom var or using some custom taxonomies as Key, because using this.

```
function wp_search_filter($query) {
 $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . 
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ( (strpos($url,'post_type=product') !== false) && is_search() ) {
$query->set('post_type', 'product');
}
return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','wp_search_filter');
```

let give a Example, You would search for a shirt, and the bone product has "shirt" word in description this wp_search will get the bone as well, it happed in a project of mine.

Comment: Your are welcome, I would like to have more free time to create a snippet for your issue, but the solution is to work with keywords and custom fields to filter, for sure it's just my opinion.